# Get Auto Recover file path of Word using Add-In

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in

How do I get the word settings like AutoRecover file location, AutoRecover time etc in VSTO Add-In using C#.
I tried, Globals.ThisAddin.Application.Options, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoRecovery Time : `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Options.SaveInterval`

AutoRecovery Path :

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(WdDefaultFilePath.wdAutoRecoverPath)
```

Comment: Great, though the correct way is: Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Options.get_DefaultFilePath(WdDefaultFilePath.wdAutoRecoverPath)

Comment: I don't see a `get_DefaultFilePath` method in 2010. Might be for an older version? This answer is correct for me.

Comment: This almost worked.  It's an indexer so had to use square brackets.  I wanted to set the value, so I used: Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Options.DefaultFilePath[Word.WdDefaultFilePath.wdAutoRecoverPath] = recoverPath;